# Gparted resizing boot partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, 14.04, gparted, ext4

So i have some unallocated space and the root partition which is pretty small. I want to add that space but it needs to move it and then grow it . I know it will take some time but i'm more concerned about wheter it is safe or not. Most of my data is backed up, but before venturing i want to know if there's a real possibility that it will result in boot failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a real possibility. gparted has been tested on many systems and drives, but it does occasionally fail. Boot failure is not the worry, as grub can be reinstalled from a livecd. The potential problem is your partition table or file system being corrupted. You should regularly backup important data anyway, in case you have a drive crash, or house burn down, etc.